# Optimization of algorithm that deals with anagrams

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am working on a project and at some point, I need to accept letters, then search trough a dictionary of words that I have, and output all words from dictionary that anagram of my accepted letters can find.

for example if I accept letters odg
the program will find words dog and god from dictionary.
The problem that I am facing is that if I accept more letters, the program takes forever to output. I kinda understand why, because anagrams are basically factorials of the given letters and this grows super fast. I was wondering if I can modify the code that I already wrote to make this program faster.

I am going to post 3 functions here, and this is where the horrible slowdown happens. Note that my dictionary is stored in binary search tree.

```
//lookup accepts the letters, which will be rearrange and searched in the BST
//it accepts function pointer callback, but do not worry about it, its just the   //way to output the words that I found.
    void DictionaryImpl::lookup(string letters, void callback(string)) const
    {
        if (callback == nullptr)
            return;

        removeNonLetters(letters);
        if (letters.empty())
            return;

        string permutation = letters;


        string tempString;

        do
        {   
            tempString=findValue(root, permutation);

            if(tempString !="!!!ValueNotFound!!!")
                callback(tempString);

            generateNextPermutation(permutation);
        } while (permutation != letters);

    }


//findValue accepts pointer to the root of the tree
//and it accepts the string that it is searching
    string DictionaryImpl::findValue(Node* p, string searchValue) const
    {
                if(p !=nullptr)
        {
            if(p ->data == searchValue)
                return searchValue;
            else if(p->data > searchValue)
                return findValue(p->left,searchValue);
            else if(p->data < searchValue)
                return findValue(p->right,searchValue);
        }
        return "!!!ValueNotFound!!!";
    }

    //accepts a string that it is going to rearrange
    void generateNextPermutation(string& permutation)
    {
        string::iterator last = permutation.end() - 1;
        string::iterator p;

        for (p = last; p != permutation.begin()  &&  *p <= *(p-1); p--)
            ;
        if (p != permutation.begin())
        {
            string::iterator q;
            for (q = p+1; q <= last  &&  *q > *(p-1); q++)
                ;
            swap(*(p-1), *(q-1));
        }
        for ( ; p < last; p++, last--)
            swap(*p, *last);
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Best way to improve code performance is finding your bottlenecks using a profiling tool..

Comment: And of course, the best way to deal with this is... to search... http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=anagram+algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ standard library already has the structures (e.g. `set`, or using `lower_bound` with a `vector`) and algorithms (`next_permutation`) you're implementing; using these is likely to be more efficient than writing your own solution.

But as you said, factorials grow really fast: what you need is a new algorithm. There's a standard trick here: two strings are anagrams of each other if and only if they are the same after you sort them. For example, sorting `dog` and `god` both give `dgo`.

By working with the sorted versions, you completely avoid the need to iterate through permutations. (in implementing an approach along these lines, knowing about `multimap` may help)

(Another alternative is to work with `multiset`s of characters; again, the multiset {d,o,g} and {g,o,d} compare equal. But sorted strings would be more efficient to work with)

Comment: Oh man, that Idea that sorted words will be equal is great, that is exactly what I needed, thank you very much.

Comment: One more thing, which sorting algorithm should I use here ?

Comment: Cant do it, The project requires not to implement anything that is not already provided.

I know how to do quickSort, will that be good here ?

Comment: @user1335175: Honestly, I would use bubble sort. It's very quick to write, hard to mess up. Maybe insertion sort or selection sort instead if you're more comfortable with it. I don't think anything you're sorting will be long enough for it to be worth spending the time writing and debugging anything more complicated -- unless you already have one written and working that you can just reuse for this project. It's a shame you're being taught to ignore the C++ standard library, though; that's a really bad habit to learn. :(

Comment: ... I think insertion sort is the popular choice anyways for efficiently sorting short sequences.